# Solr Issues Using Multilist Property on Search Result

Tags: content-search, solr

I have a multilist field on article items called `Categories`. In a module I am trying to filter based on one or more items in that multilist field. I can do this if I directly supply the name of the field in the index to use as follows:

```
var filterPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<ArticleSearchResultItem>();

if (categories?.Any() == true)
{
   foreach (var category in categories)
   {
      filterPredicate = filterPredicate
         .Or(p => p["article_categories_sm"].Contains(category));
   }

   predicate = predicate.And(filterPredicate);
}
```

When I try to do this by adding article categories to my `ArticleSearchResultItem` it seems that the value the property gets is always null.

```
public class ArticleSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("publish_date")]
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [IndexField("article_categories")]
    public IEnumerable<ID> ArticleCategories { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var categoryIds = categories?.Where(ShortID.IsShortID)
   .Select(cat => ShortID.Parse(cat).ToID());
if (categoryIds?.Any() == true)
{
   var filterPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<ArticleSearchResultItem>();
   foreach (var category in categoryIds)
   {
      filterPredicate = filterPredicate
         .Or(p => p.ArticleCategories.Contains(category));
   }

   predicate = predicate.And(filterPredicate);
}
```

I tested having a suffix of `_sm` for the `IndexField` attribute above `ArticleCategories` and had the same results (all items were filtered when filtering by the same category that worked in the first block of code). `Publish Date` is also a custom field however that seems to be working fine (in queries shown by the search log it shows up as `publish_date_tdt`). When I look in the search logs it seems that using the property `ArticleCategories` causes the query to use `article_categories_t` which does not exist on my items. Could this be an issue with my schema or config? This instance is Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 170614).

Comment: Have you checked what is sent to Solr if you use `[IndexField("article_categories")]`? Have you tried to use a field without `_` character in its name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case it works fine with `p["article_categories_sm"].Contains(category)` I suggest trying the following changes:

```
public class ArticleSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
    {
        [IndexField("publish_date")]
        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

        [IndexField("article_categories_sm")]
        [TypeConverter(typeof(Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldEnumerableConverter))]
        public virtual IEnumerable<ID> ArticleCategories { get; set; }
    }
```

I added the TypeConverter and made the field virtual.

If it doesn't work, trying without `"_sm"`

Comment: You shouldn't need the `_sm` suffix - the type converter will fix the issue.

Comment: @RichardSeal I know Solr uses the “_sm” postfix for string fields and we don’t need to use it in the field name. But Teeknow wrote that query with “_sm” works fine for him. I decided to propose trying both various.

Comment: yes, a few times (and i don't really know why) I also had to specify list field name with _sm suffix because it was not added by converter.

Comment: For me, I have a field name hmc_filters I have seen both values i.e. hmc_filters_sm and hmc_filters in document.Fields Array. But my results are still not mapping this field in my searchresultitem class. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I would inspect the Search.log file to compare the queries that are actually sent to Solr for the working version and the non-working version, this approach has helped me many times in the past. You can also if need be paste the serialized query directly into the url of your solr instance:

https://localhost:8983/solr/#/core_name/query?q=SERIALIZED-QUERY

That way you can see what results get returned and tweak.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled my solr instance and things started to work as expected using the code provided by @ArtsemPrashkovich's answer without the `_sm` suffix. I was running version 6.5 and switched it to be 5.1. According to the compatibility chart solr 6.5 was not supported by default for the version of Sitecore I was using: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897.